# Python game with list of dictionaries/ each question has 2 parts

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries with questions. Need to loop over the dictionaries one at a time, can be done randomly as well. Each question has 2 parts and need to go through them separately.

**For example**: question - `'Am I dog?'` if the user answers `'yes'`, they should get `'bark'`, if they answer `'no'`, they should get `'what am I?'`.

The code is as follows:

```
qa = [{"question": "Am I a dog?", "yes": "bark?",
        "no": "Am I a cat?"},

        {"question": "Are you a lion?", "yes": "growl?", 
        "no": "Am I an elephant?"},

       {"question": "Am I a person?", "yes": "speak?",
       "no": "Am I an animal"},

       {"question": "Am I winter?", "yes": "snow?",
       "no": "Am I summer"}]

user1 = []

for i in qa:
    print(i)
    answer1 = input("enter 'yes' or 'no'.\n").lower()
    if 'yes' in answer1:
        user1.append('yes')
        if 'yes' in answer1:
            print('what do I do?')
            user1.append(qa.value[i]) # doesn't work
        else:
            print("error")
    elif 'no' in answer1:
        user1.append('no')
        if 'no' in answer1:
            print('what am I?')
            user1.append(qa.value[i]) #doesn't work
        else:
            print("error")
    else:
        print("error")
print(user1)
```

I need the user to see just the question, then if they enter 'yes' they get the value of yes, and if they enter 'no' they get the value of no. Right now the code is showing the entire value of a "question" which I do not want. Help, please.

Comment: Why do you need user1 list?

Comment: `print(i)` should be `print(i["question"])`

Comment: @PatrickJane to store the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are basically checking the same condition twice.

> ```
> if 'yes' in answer1:
>     user1.append('yes')
>     if 'yes' in answer1:
> ```

A slightly better version of your program with same logic just a different syntax would be:

```py
user1 = []
for i in qa:
    print(i)
    answer1 = input("enter 'yes' or 'no'.\n").lower()
    print(i.get(answer1, ''))
    user1.append(answer1)
```

**SAMPLE RUN**:

```py
    Am I a dog?
    enter 'yes' or 'no'.
>>> no
    Am I a cat?
    Are you a lion?
    enter 'yes' or 'no'.
>>> yes
    growl?
    Am I a person?
    enter 'yes' or 'no'.
>>> no
    Am I an animal
    Am I winter?
    enter 'yes' or 'no'.
>>> yes
    snow?
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work. i is a dictionary itself so I did a key look-up with i.

```
    qa = [{"question": "Am I a dog?", "yes": "bark?",
           "no": "Am I a cat?"},

          {"question": "Are you a lion?", "yes": "growl?",
           "no": "Am I an elephant?"},

          {"question": "Am I a person?", "yes": "speak?",
           "no": "Am I an animal"},

          {"question": "Am I winter?", "yes": "snow?",
           "no": "Am I summer"}]

    user1 = []

    for i in qa:
        print(i["question"])
        answer1 = input("enter 'yes' or 'no'.\n").lower()
        if 'yes' in answer1:
            user1.append('yes')
            if 'yes' in answer1:
                print('what do I do?')
                user1.append(i["yes"])  # should work
            else:
                print("error")
        elif 'no' in answer1:
            user1.append('no')
            if 'no' in answer1:
                print('what am I?')
                user1.append(i["no"])  # should work
            else:
                print("error")
        else:
            print("error")
    print(user1)
```

Comment: Thanks Caleb it does the printing of the questions correctly, but depends on whether user answer yes or no, I need the value of that answer @Caleb Sadler